# tagging text and looping to open file with external application

Tags: loops, python-3.x, tkinter, textbox, tags

I have a text widget that displays a column of data 'dwg', clicking on any of this data should open an external PDF application. I appear to be having a problem with loop, in that the tag isn't working and subsequently the opening of the file. Where have I gone wrong ?

```
def displayFile():
    for f in os.listdir("c:\\pdf"):
        if f.endswith(".pdf"):
            pdflink="dwg" + f
            path="c:\\pdf"
            self.textbox.insert(END,f + "\n", "dwg")
            self.textbox.tag_configure(pdflink, foreground="#0078D7", underline=False)             
            self.textbox.tag_bind(pdflink, "<Double-Button-1>", lambda event, filename = path+'/'+ f: subprocess.run(['c:\program files\sumatraPDF\sumatraPDF',filename]) )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tag you're adding to the text is `"dwg"`, but the tag you're configuring and binding is `"dwg"+f`.

```
self.textbox.insert(END, f+"\n", pdflink) # or "dwg" + f if you prefer
```

Comment: what I'm attempting (and possibly doing incorrectly) is to add a .pdf suffix to the end of the "dwg" data. The reason for this is the 'dwg' data matches pdf files located in directory c:\\pdf. eg my text widget displays 3 lines of data each with different 'dwg' data, such as abcd or efgh or wxyz. I want to be able to add a .pdf suffix ie abcd.pdf and then open my external application.

Comment: Yes, it should be doing that correctly- you just aren't tagging the text you insert. Or rather, the tag going on it is "dwg", but you aren't binding the open-file lambda to the "dwg" tag, you're binding the open-file lambda to the "dwg"+f tag (i.e. "dwgmyfilename.pdf"), which isn't in the text. Get the clicky-tag and the inserted tag to match, and it should help

Comment: thanks @delioth, I've sort of got it working, unfortunately its opening the same PDF for anything I click, but thats out of scope of my original question :)